# SMPS transformer datasheet specifics

Tags: transformer, switch-mode-power-supply, parallel, series, winding

Here is an excerpt from a typical ferrite switching transformer datasheet:

[image: Wurth-Electronik 750311771 Datasheet]

This happens to be the [Wurth 750311771](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/445/750311771-3096825.pdf).

Questions:

1. Two standard primaries are depicted on the left. This datasheet implies that they will be wired in parallel for 100-400 V input. But could they be wired in series for 200-800 V input? The insulation rating is 2000 V/1 min.
2. Why are the primaries drawn separately, instead of "stacked on top of each other" like the secondaries?
3. The secondaries look misleading, as visually they are all different sizes, so should be different voltages. Why are these drawn "stacked on top of each other", instead of individually like the primaries?
4. Also about the secondaries, 15 V@3 A must be for all three in parallel. Since they all have the same resistance (50 mΩ) could they be used independently, or wired in series for 45 V@1 A? Are there any caveats stemming from how they are drawn?

Comment: Just treat the symbol as an artistic impression and use the table in the sheet for understanding things.

Comment: (With all entries in the table referring to terminal 1 showing `tie(2+3)`, I take the label between terminals 2+3 to refer to a series connection, not even a dashed connection sketched notwithstanding: *halve* voltage mentioned for parallel connection.)

Answer (score 1):

They might be hinting at sectioned windings versus multi-filar or parallel winding.  But it is just a schematic, and not a winding diagram; don't take it too seriously.

The table suggests to connect the primary halves in series (`tie(2+3)`, wire to pins 1, 4) and the secondary parts in parallel (`tie(7+8+9)` and `10+11+12`).  However they're actually arranged inside, this seems like what they are implying.

As far as alternative uses, mind that, for example, the isolation between primary/aux windings is not specified, so it can be assumed functional at best.  So don't use this for, like, an isolated DC-DC with high voltage input and output (primary halves as primary and secondary).